# Inserting a word(char[]) into a structure word(char[]) in C

Tags: c, struct, text-files, scanf

So i'm reading each word from a textfile which contains many words that are not unique. I'm supposed find the number of unique words and store those words into a structure variable called word

My main problem is labeled under the comment "MY PROBLEM IS HERE BELOW"

Struct Code:

```
  typedef struct {
  char word[101];
  int  freq;

  } WordArray;
```

Code:

```
  //temp[i].word is a temporary structure that scans ALL words
  //input[i].word is the structure with unique words

  word = fscanf(finput, "%s", &temp[i].word);

 //if the word in temp[i] is in input[j].word then it is not unique
 // so frequency of word is incremented

   for(j = 0; j < 200; j++) { 
     if(strcmp(temp[i].word,input[j].word) == 0){
        contains = 1;
        input[j].freq++;
     }
  }

     // MY PROBLEM IS HERE BELOW
    if(contains != 1) { // since contains is not 1 then it is unique

     input[i].word = temp[i].word // i want to put this word in input[i].word but this
                                  // produces incompatible type error
                                  // i tried strcpy and strncpy no luck...
     input[i].freq++;
     uniqueWords++;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `&`

```
fscanf(finput, "%s", &temp[i].word);
```

change it to

```
fscanf(finput, "%s", temp[i].word);
```

Or take the address of the first element, which is equivalent to the previous line

```
fscanf(finput, "%s", &temp[i].word[0]);
```

the passed array decays to a pointer to the first element of the array, so these both are equivalent

```
fscanf(finput, "%s", temp[i].word); /* passed a pointer to the first elemn */
fscanf(finput, "%s", &temp[i].word[0]); /* passed the address of the first element */
```

also, add a limit to `fscanf` to prevent buffer overflow like this

```
fscanf(finput, "%100s", temp[i].word); /* passed a pointer to the first elemn */
```

where the number should be `1` fewer than the array size.

You can't assign to arrays this line

```
input[i].word = temp[i].word
```

is wrong, you should use `strcpy`

```
strcpy(input[i].word, temp[i].word);
```

Comment: When i replaced fscanf with yours i still get the error "error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[101]’ from type ‘char *’"

Comment: in what line you get that error, do you have a `temp[i].word = something;`?

Comment: but when i replace the other line where i have the problem with "input[i].word[0] = temp[i].word[0];" it works but obviously this will not work when i want to store all words in this array

Comment: @geforce I see, i added the solution to the answer, the one in comment means assign the first character of `temp[i].word` to ther first character of `input[i].word` that's why it works, but you cant assign to arrays in c.

Comment: perhaps i manually copy all chars from temp to input array using a counter such as temp[i].word[j] = temp[i].word[j] using a for-loop?

Comment: @gefoce it would work, but don't do it there is a standard function for that use `strcpy`

Comment: If you look above on my comments i said i tried strcpy and strncpy and they do not work either for some reason it also produces the error " warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’"

Comment: you have to include `string.h`

Comment: oh wow thanks didn't know that would cause that many problems thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
word = fscanf(finput, "%s", &temp[i].word);
```

Should really be more like:

```
if( 1 != fscanf(finput, " %100s", temp[i].word) )
{ // fscanf failed
    perror( "fscanf failed");
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, fscanf successful
```

Comment: why post two answers?  Pick one, add content that is relevant, then you can delete the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct {
    char word[101];
    int  freq;
} WordArray;
```

That just obscures the code, making it more difficult to read/understand/maintain, much better to use:

```
#define MAX_WORDS (200)
#define MAX_WORD_LEN (100)

struct WordArray 
{
    char word[MAX_WORD_LEN+1];
    int  freq;
};

struct WordArray input[MAX_WORDS];
```

For reading words, counting duplicates:

```
    int  numWords = 0;
    BOOL dupFound = false;
    char tempWord[101];

    // prep save area 'input[]'
    memset( input, 0x00, sizeof(input) );

    // prep for first iteration through while loop
    memset(tempWord, 0x00, sizeof(tempWord) );

    // note leading ' ' in format string
    // note sizing of input to avoid buffer overrun
    while( 1 != fscanf(finput, " %[MAX_WORD_LEN]s", tempWord) ) 
    {

        dupFound = false;
        for j = 0;j<MAX_WORDS;j++)
        {
            if( 0 == strcmp(tempWord, input[j].word) )
            { // then dup word found

                input[j].freq++;
                dupFound = true;
                break;
            } // end if
        } // end for


        if( !dupFound )
        { // then, add new word

            strcpy( input[numWords].word, tempWord );
            input[numWords].freq = 1;
            numWords++;
        } // end if

        // prep for next iteration of while loop
        memset(tempWord, 0x00, sizeof(tempWord) );
    } // end while
```

The comparison should be: